# How can I mock multiple get axios request in Jest unit test for an async action that calls a few more async actions?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, axios

I'm using axios mock for testing redux actions in my app. I stuck with the problem of testing an async action function that sends `POST` request and dispatches a few more async actions that send their own `GET` requests. How can I manage that using mocks?

Actions:

```
export function recordStepCompleted(step, isNewLevel = true) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        // setUserTaskComplete() action sends `POST` request
        dispatch(setUserTaskComplete(step))
            .then(() => isNewLevel && dispatch(rewardsActions.getUserLevels()));
        dispatch({
            type: types.RECORD_STEP_COMPLETED,
            payload: { step }
        });
    };
}
```

```
export function getUserLevels() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(getAchievements()) // it sends GET request
            .then(achievements => {
                dispatch({ type: types.GET_LEVELS.REQUEST });
                return api.getLevels() // it also sends GET request
                    .then(res => {
                        //......
                        dispatch({
                            type: types.GET_LEVELS.SUCCESS,
                            payload: { levels: { ...res.data, ... } }
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(error => /*....*/);
            });
    };
}
```

So, in total, I need to mock three different requests to test the `recordStepCompleted` action but I don't know how. Please, help me with that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios or mock `dispatch` in your test.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend AxiosStatic Interface to create your own and use  jest.fn() to
pass your responses:

```
    import axios, { AxiosStatic } from "axios";
    jest.mock("axios");

    interface AxiosMock extends AxiosStatic {
    mockResolvedValue: (promise: Promise<Partial<AxiosResponse>>) => void;
    mockRejectedValue: (error: Partial<AxiosError>) => void;
    mockResolvedValueOnce: (promise: Promise<Partial<AxiosResponse>>) => this;
}

    const mockAxios = axios as AxiosMock;
    const myMock = jest.fn();
        myMock
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ "Your DATA 1" })
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ "Your DATA 2" })
            .mockReturnValueOnce({ "Your DATA 3" });

        mockAxios
            .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve(myMock()))
            .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve(myMock()))
            .mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(myMock()));
```